# Can't do migration with Laravel and Xampp

Tags: laravel, xampp

I can't do a migration in Laravel with `php artisan migrate`
I'm using Xampp to work locally, and i've already created the DB (recycling).
This is my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=recycling
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

In terminal when i use `php artisan migrate` i get this:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = recycling and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you create a database named `recycling`?

Comment: yes i do. cmd + c , cmd+ v not to write it wrong

Comment: Did you try to replace `localhost` by `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: they both don't work

Answer (score 0):

It can be the issue related to the cache or config cached generated by Laravel.

- change the DATABASE_HOST in .env file to 127.0.0.1
- run php artisan optimize:clear
- run php artisan migrate:install

FYI please check whether the database server is running on your machine or not.

I hope the above step solves the issue.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = recycling and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Comment: Check the MySql working on not on your system!

Answer (score 0):

if your using xampp it really using it will actually use its own database, it won't use the database you set

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).